# Webpack version 4 installation does not work

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-4

For my Vue project I need to use webpack, specifically version 4 in consideration with my other dependencies.
However, whenever I try to npm install webpack@4 --save-dev it just enters a loop that never ends and seems buggy.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

I tried Googling the issue and visited stackoverflow. But none of the other suggestions I found worked for me.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue could be since the npm install command in normal circumstances has no problems.  You'll need to provide more information for others to understand your specific circumstances and why the command is not working.  Normally, all you need to do is create a new folder, then in that folder run commands `npm init` followed by `npm install webpack@4 --save-dev`.  Are you doing anything different?  What versions of Node and NPM are you on?  Does the install loop you're experiencing have any error messages?  It could be useful to add some of the log to your question.

Comment: If you're open to using the vue-cli build tool, the answer I posted should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the official Vue 2 scaffolding tool, [vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/).  If you already have it installed and it's version number is >= 5.x (check with command `vue --version`), it will install webpack 5, so first uninstall it with `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`.  Reinstall using a version number that will install webpack 4:

```shell
npm install -g @vue/cli@4.5.19
```

Then run the command to create a new Vue project, `vue create my-project`.

This will scaffold a Vue project for you with webpack 4. You can confirm by checking `"node_modules/webpack"` in package.json.